# Florida Sitecore User Group - Tuesday, November 14th, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time EST:** Tuesday, November 14, 2017, Starts at 6:00 PM

**Date/Time UTC:** Tuesday, November 14, 2017, Starts at 11:00 PM

**Location:** Margaritaville Hollywood Beach Resort, 1111 N. Ocean Drive, Hollywood, FL

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Florida-Sitecore-User-Group/events/244061151/

Join us @ Margaritaville, Hollywood Beach, Tuesday Nov 14th, for our next South Florida Sitecore User Group.  Regardless of whether or not you made it to Sitecore Symposium this year, there will be some great insight shared and plenty of opportunity to learn more about Sitecore's latest release, how customers are are leveraging the platform well beyond content management and to explore the latest strategies for integrating Sitecore with other tools in the technology stack to deliver measurable, repeatable business outcomes and customer insights.

Drinks, hors d'oeuvres and networking: 6 to 7 PM (11 PM to 12 AM UTC)

**Presentations:** 7 to 9 PM (12 to 2 AM UTC)

- Translations.com... the impact of localization.  Niklas Schlappkohl, Senior Director, Travel Solutions @ Translations.com, will share case studies on global initiatives and highlight how leading travel companies have boosted their ROI by optimizing localization strategies.
- Chick-Fil-A & Herschend Family Entertainment... two customer-centric organizations are using Sitecore and their integrated tech stack to drive repeatable and predictable business outcomes.  Hear the latest case study results on how personalized, cross-channel strategies and stellar brand experiences are delivering record-setting business metrics.
- The "Digital Consumer" in 2017 (and beyond!). Sitecore's Digital Evangelist Gene De Libero will reveal how companies that focus solely on transactional relationships are floundering, while companies that implement a solid digital strategy to deliver remarkable customer experiences are winning customers for life.

Come out and network and check it out.

Comment: Please add UTC times.

Comment: @RichardSeal Done, let me know if you need anything else?

Comment: Thanks - event added.